# How can a portal user modify his own partner data in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I was trying to create a module, where portal users could modify the associated partner data. But I get a security error that only admin users could modify configs.

> File
>   ".../server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_config.py",
>   line 541, in execute
>       raise openerp.exceptions.AccessError(_("Only administrators can change the settings"))

I tried giving it security access like this:

> access_config_portal,portal_partner_config.settings,model_portal_partner_config_settings,base.group_portal,1,1,0,0

But didn't work... i think it's becouse the error shows that in res_config.py execute function it's check the users to be SUPERUSER:

```
 if uid != SUPERUSER_ID and not self.pool['res.users'].has_group(cr, uid, 'base.group_erp_manager'):
            raise openerp.exceptions.AccessError(_("Only administrators can change the settings"))
```

Like this:

```
class Configuration(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'
    _name = 'portal_partner_config.settings'

    name = fields.Char()
    street = fields.Char()
    city = fields.Char()

    @api.model
    def get_default_inova_values(self,fields):
       users = self.pool.get('res.users')
       current_user = users.browse(self._cr, self._uid, self._uid, context=self._context)
       name = current_user.partner_id.name
       street = current_user.partner_id.street
       city = current_user.partner_id.city

       return {
            'name': name,
            'street': street,
            'city': city,}

    @api.one
    def set_inova_values(self):
        users = self.pool.get('res.users')
        current_user = users.browse(self._cr, self._uid, self._uid, context=self._context)
        users.sudo().write(self._cr, self._uid, current_user.id, {'name': self.name,
                                                           'street': self.street,
                                                           'city': self.city,
                                                          },
                                                            context=self._context)
```

There a way to portal users change their custom data, an associate a payment source, like a credit card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

In the view definition change the call method of the res_config like this:

```
<button string="Apply" type="object" name="execute2" class="oe_highlight" />
```

and in the res_config model copy the execute def and erase the SUPERUSERID check.
I don't overrite the execute function so in the others config the SUPERUSERID check is perfom